# vim - forcing >> to use spaces, not tabs

Tags: vim

I have these settings my my .vimrc:

```
set softtabstop=4
set shiftwidth=4
set tabstop=4
set expandtab
```

I am also using tpope's sensible.vim plugin.

When I use >> to indent, it is using a tab rather than spaces.

How can I have >> insert spaces?

Here is the output of :set

```
:set
--- Options ---
  ambiwidth=double    binary              history=1000        nrformats=hex       scrolloff=1         smarttab            tabpagemax=50       ttyfast
  autoindent          display=lastline    incsearch           number              shiftwidth=4        softtabstop=4       tabstop=4           ttymouse=xterm2
  autoread          noendofline           laststatus=2        ruler               showcmd             suffixesadd=.js     ttimeout            wildmenu
  background=dark     helplang=en       nomodeline            scroll=20           sidescrolloff=5   noswapfile            ttimeoutlen=100     t_Co=16
  backspace=indent,eol,start
  complete=.,w,b,u,t
  fileencodings=ucs-bom,utf-8,default,latin1
  fileformats=unix,dos,mac
  guioptions=aegimrLt
  listchars=tab:> ,trail:-,extends:>,precedes:<,nbsp:+
  printoptions=paper:letter
  runtimepath=~/.vim,~/.vim/bundle/syntastic,/var/lib/vim/addons,/usr/share/vim/vimfiles,/usr/share/vim/vim74,/usr/share/vim/vimfiles/after,/var/lib/vim/addons/after,~/.vim/after
  sessionoptions=blank,buffers,curdir,folds,help,tabpages,winsize
  suffixes=.bak,~,.swp,.o,.info,.aux,.log,.dvi,.bbl,.blg,.brf,.cb,.ind,.idx,.ilg,.inx,.out,.toc
  tags=./tags;,./TAGS,tags,TAGS
  viminfo=!,'100,<50,s10,h
```

Comment: Can you tell us what the output of `:set` is? Preferably in a file where this problem occurs?

Comment: Does it happen when you forego loading sensible.vim?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something has `:set[local] noexpandtab`. This can be through plugins or filetype plugins. You can find out (for a particular buffer) via `:verbose setlocal expandtab?`.

For plugins, you can re-set the option after they have been sourced:

```
autocmd VimEnter * set expandtab
```

For filetype plugins, you can override the setting for individual filetypes in `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/<filetype>.vim`, or you turn them off entirely by commenting out the `:filetype plugin on` from your `~/.vimrc`.

Comment: Thanks for the verbose setlocal expandtab? test. It said that expandtab was set in my .vimrc.

After closing vim and re-opening it's working now. I guess I could have just sourced the file.

Comment: actually, it seems that
autocmd VimEnter * set expandtab
was the answer for me.